# Is there a way for a pthread to do certain things after it receives the cancellation request?

Tags: c, pthreads

If I call `pthread_cancel(pid);` in main thread, and in worker thread I set
`pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);`
`pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_???);`
I want the worker thread to do something (e.g. break out of a while loop) only after it receives a cancellation request.
Is it possible in C?
Thank you.

Comment: I do not understand your explanation. What is `???` doing here? Is this XY question? Could you explain the real problem you are trying to solve? `Is there a way for a pthread to do certain things after it receives the cancellation request?` Yes, "there is a way". So did you read `pthread_cancel` documentation? `When a cancellation requested is acted on, the following steps occur for thread` - and it lists all the steps that happen... Here's the documentation for you: https://man.archlinux.org/man/pthread_cancel.3.en

Comment: The first rule of `pthread_cancel()` is: do not call `pthread_cancel()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take you to be asking about setting up a thread so that it responds to cancellation requests, but in some way other than terminating.  No, this is not possible.  You have (only) these options around cancellation:

- whether a thread can be cancelled at all (its cancelstate property).  A thread can toggle this for itself, and it works similarly to a signal mask: a cancel request directed to a (then) non-cancelable thread remains pending until such time as the thread makes itself cancelable.
- whether a thread is asynchronously cancelable (such that cancellation requests can affect a thread at any point in its execution) or whether cancellation requests can be acted on only at cancellation points.

Those are strictly about the *circumstances* under which a cancellation request is acted upon.  The *effect* of a cancellation request against a given thread being acted upon is always that the thread is prematurely terminated (*i.e.* cancelled).

And you should never do that, because it carries a high risk of leaving the program in an inconsistent state.

It sounds like you may be looking for `pthread_kill()`, with which you can deliver a chosen signal to a thread.  You can register a signal-handling function that will be called when such a signal is received.  That can also interrupt system calls, though there are a couple that will automatically resume after a signal is handled.

Alternatively, there may be other approaches more appropriate for your specific circumstances, but these move farther away from the behavior of thread cancellation.

Comment: Wow, this good explanation, even though the question is not very clear to some standards. XD